# How can I describe the time schedule of a plan?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, adjectives

I'm making a plan of what shall we do during the next N months:

- Plan A: do a lot of jobs in a short time. People may feel stress.
- Plan B: do few jobs in a long time. People may feel satisfied.

How can I describe Plan A? An urgent/pressing/intense/strained plan?
And how can I describe Plan B? A loose/relaxed/eased plan?

The plan is a self-learning plan without direct external pressure. With plan A, someone may feel stressful. With plan B, we may used too long time but just learn few things. So, it's up to us to make the decision. If I make several other plans, for example:

- Plan A: do most amount of jobs in shortest time.
- Plan B
- ...
- Plan X: do fewest jobs in longest time.

How can I describe them respectively? Just like we describe different "high": very high, ultra high, super high, extremely high, tremendously high, etc.

Comment: Plan A is 'on a tight schedule' (note the spelling). It's only urgent or pressing if the tasks _have_ to be done quickly. You could call Plan B a more relaxed schedule.

Comment: I like the suggestions from @KateBunting. Depending on the context, I might also call plan A ["ambitious"](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/ambitious).

Comment: What's the full context, like where you're saying it, and the sentence where you're going to be using it?